# Blazor - Using Cascading Authentication State Between Different Layouts

Tags: authentication, razor, layout, blazor

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Blazor project where there will be 3 sub-folders within the application that serve up a single page each whose content will be WebGL driven using Three.JS.

In the first folder I am testing with, I have created two items. The first is named "_TestPage.cshtml" and the other is named "Index.razor". Both pages have the following @page directive in them:

```
@page "/Applications/TestFolder1/Index"
```

The _TestPage.cshtml page contains the following within it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <app>
            <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
        </app>
    </body>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <title>My Blazor App</title>

        <base href="/" />

        <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
</html>
```

The Index.razor page also has the following within it:

```
@layout EmptyLayout
@page "/Applications/Monitor/Index"

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <p style="color: black;">***I can not see this text either...***</p>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <RedirectNotAuthorizedAccess />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

However, when the app starts up, I am able to go directly to the Index page in the sub-folder without having to log in. I get a solid red background but do not see any rendered text nor do I get redirected to the login page as it should since I have not logged in.

Is there something different I need to be doing to have Cascading Authentication State work when I'm not using the default "MainLayout" component creating by Visual Studio and have over-written the layout inside a razor page using the @layout directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I may have solved my issue. It appears that two things were setup incorrectly. The first was that my "EmptyLayout" component did not have the "AuthroizeView" componenet defined in it to handle users not authenticated. The second was that my "RedirectNotAuthorizedAccess" component was not doing a "forceLoad = true" when redirecting to the login page using "NavigationManager". This was preventing the login page from showing and still displaying the solid red background from the nest CSTHML layout from my example in the original post.

The code for the CSHTML page above remains the same and now my two other components are coded as follows:

Index.razor

```
@page "/Application/TestFolder1/Index"
@layout EmptyLayout

@code {

}
```

EmptyLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase;

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <p style="color: green;">I can now see this text...</p>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <RedirectNotAuthorizedAccess />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Answer (score 6):

I am fixed this issue sample way and work for me perfect,

use [Blazor authentication and authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for detect user Authorized or not by using JWT or any process for Authorized user

for change user auth or not using `GetAuthenticationStateAsync` override method

I am using JWT for detected user login success or not

```
string token = await TokenAsync();
        ClaimsIdentity identity = await IsAuthenticated(token)
            ? new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "mrfibuli"), "Fake authentication type") // true, auth
            : new ClaimsIdentity(); // false, no auth
        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
```

Can you use [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implement-a-custom-authenticationstateprovider) always true

Then can you change **App.razor** for response **AuthenticationStateProvider service**

**App.razor**

```
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeView>
                <Authorized>
                    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
                </Authorized>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <CascadingAuthenticationState>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(EmptyLayout)">
                    <p>No Found</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </CascadingAuthenticationState>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

`<RedirectToLogin />` Create ony for Redirect To Login if user expired or no auth

**`RedirectToLogin.razor`**

```
    @page "/NotAuthorized/RedirectToLogin"
    <iServicePayroll.Pages.Home.Login />
```

`iServicePayroll.Pages.Home.Login` my login page